# PHP - Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mysqlnd

I moved my project to a cloud hosting and now I have some problems with it.
As I know, mysqli_stmt::get_result() works only with mysql native driver.
Also, according to the documentation, it has to be added when PHP is compiled.

This is my phpinfo():
[image: phpinfo]

mysqli does not included in api extensions.
My question is if it can be added somehow without recompiling PHP?

Comment: "Cloud hosting" means some shared hosting where you did not install PHP yourself? Then no, or contact your host. Otherwise: need more details.

Comment: mysqli is a driver that needs to be installed. There's not much you can do about it. Talk to the people hosting the server and ask them to install it.

Comment: It is a dedicated server and I can do with it what I want. The problem is that I don't want to recompile it.

Comment: Most servers/operating systems allow the simple installation of PHP and its extensions via repositories, e.g. `apt-get install php5-mysqli` or such. You'll have to provide more information about how you installed PHP in order for us to advise anything.